# Eisenbud: if $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, then after choosing generators, $A = k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I$ for some ideal $I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

This is in the proof to Corollary 1.8 on page 34.

How do we prove that every $k$-algebra can be written in this form, for some ideal $I$?

$k$ is an algebraically closed field if that matters.

I understand that a finitely generated $k$-algebra is already in this form for $I=(0)$, is that good enough for the converse of the proof?  The corollary is:

> **Corollary 1.8** If $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $A$ is a $k$-algebra, then $A = A(X) \equiv k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I(X)$ for some algebraica set $X$ iff $A$ is reduced and finitely generated as a $k$-algebra.

The proof goes:

> If $A = A(X)$ for some $X \subset k^n$, then $A = k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I(X)$ is generated as a $k$-algebra by $x_1, \dots, x_n$.  Since $I(X)$ is a radical ideal, $A$ is reduced.
>      Conversely, if $A$ is a a finitely generated $k$-algebra, then after choosing generators we may write $A = k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I$ for some ideal $I$.  SInce $A$ is reduced, $I$ is a radical ideal.  Thus $I = I(Z(I))$ by the Nullstellensatz, and we may take $X = Z(I)$.

I guess I'm not seeing how we can talk about some ideal $I$ in the converse proof.  How does this ideal arise given a finitely generated $k$-algebra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_1,...,a_n$ generators of $A$, define $f:k[x_1,...,x_n]\rightarrow A$ by $f(x_i)=a_i$, its kernel is $I$ and $A\simeq k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$.

Comment: I would rather write, "its kernel is an ideal $I$, and...", given that you haven't told us what $I$ is.

Comment: So another definition of $k$-algebra is that there exists a ring homomorphism of $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ onto $A$?

Comment: Another definition of finite generated $k$-algebra.

Comment: Thanks.  Now I understand.

Comment: That's a *commutative* finitely generated $k$-algebra.